# Which one is the right one here? ('d / 've) / (gathering / meeting) / (before / until)

Tags: sentence-construction

> I'd had a high school reuion party at Hongdae, but the party was over too early. So, some of us decided to drink more at a park located in Hongdae. At the park, there were a group of girls sitting on a bench, holding a bottle of beer. And, most of them were pretty, so we decided to go there and talk to them. It was a lot of fun because I **('d/'ve)** never done that before. The **(gathering / meeting)** was over about an hour later. We had been talking to them for about an hour **(before/until)** the time when I had to go home to be on time for the last bus.

1. I think 'd is right because I'm talking about my experience until I met them.
2. I don't know what I should choose. can you give me an advice?
3. I think until *could* imply that we had been talking more than one hour, so that I missed the bus. but before would never imply that because the event of talking to them has to be finished before the time I had to go home. I think depending on what I mean, I can choose which I should use, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 'd is indeed correct
2. Meeting- An assembly or conference of persons for a specific purpose.

Gathering- An assemblage of people; group or crowd.

So for Number 2, I think *Gathering* would be better between the 2 options, but since you had never met them before, I would suggest the word *encounter* to be substituted into that place.

3. I believe for this part neither of your two options will fit nicely into that sentence. I suggest you instead replace the options with *till*.

Till- up to the time of; until

You can still use *until* in your sentence by restructuring it to:

We had been talking to them for about an hour **until it was** time when I had to go home to be on time for the last bus.

Comment: Thank you so much and I think 'was' is right here. and how about what I've added at the end of the sentence? Does that makes sense ?-->We had been talking to them for about an hour until it "was" time when I had to leave the place to be on time for the last bus. but I didn't go home on that day. vs

Comment: The last part is clumsy. It  could be condensed as "until I had to leave to catch the last bus home".